# How can I increase the size of Object limit with http post request in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
$http({
    url: '/abc',
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    timeout: 90000,
    params: {
        Data: $scope.Quote,
        servicetype: 'persist'
    }
}).success(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Not Success");
});
```

> I have an an Object that frequently increase the object size with HTTP Post request. After the limit this type of error occur. 400 (Bad Request) & 505 HTTP Version Not Supported.
>   When delete some records from Data Base the request implemented
>   Call HTTP Post request for many times the Error occur with increase size of the object limit. 400 (Bad Request) & 505 HTTP Version Not Supported.

Comment: Objects don't really have a length in the sense that arrays and strings do. Are you talking about setting the `Data` property to longer string values, or...? If you are getting an error for specific data then please [edit] your question to show that data.

Comment: What technology (PHP, ASP.NET,...) handles the post?

Comment: I presume with Tomcat serving the application?

Comment: Your server logs generally provide clues as to why the 400 and 505 errors are occurring. Have you checked them? This sounds more like a server issue (configuration change, perhaps?) rather than an Angular issue.

Comment: i am calling Java SOAP webServices?