# how can i fix the 505 HTTP version Not Supported error in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

**Code**

```
$http({
        url: '/ABC',
        method: 'POST',
        async: false,
        params: {
            addData: $scope.Data,
            servicetype: 'persistQuote'
        }
    }).success(function (response, opts) {
        console.log(response);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Not Successfull");
    });
```

> Error occur when call HTTP Post request with JSON large Object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increase the size of Object limit with http post request in Angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137601/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-object-limit-with-http-post-request-in-angularjs)

Comment: Seems to me like a server-side issue rather than Angular http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E505.html Check server logs